# RStudio / RMarkdown: Can output be set to both "inline" and "in console"?

Tags: rstudio, r-markdown

Is there any way to have Rmd output be set to both "chunk output inline" and "chunk output in console"?

I like having things inline, but i also like simultaneously having plots go to a zoomed plot window I have on another monitor.  Is there any setting that allows both simultaneously?

IE: have both of these settings at the same time:

```
output: 
  html_document:
    toc: true
    toc_float: true
    toc_depth: 3
editor_options: 
  chunk_output_type: inline
```

and

```
output: 
  html_document:
    toc: true
    toc_float: true
    toc_depth: 3
editor_options: 
  chunk_output_type: console
```

Comment: Has this been resolved? I'm also interested in this solution. Thanks!

Comment: It has not been resolved